# MS Access Database update

Tags: ms-access

I have an application which uses ms access database with password encryption. The login information is stored within the database (username and password). I double clicked the database file and keyed in the password to see the table list. In a message bar there's a massage stating that the "This database has been opened read-only". Then I tried to set the password into a new value lets say "password1". However, when I re run my application and tried to login using the new password but it fails (only works with the old password).

Does this mean the database here is not used by the application? Or there's a copy of the database somewhere and being referred to ?

Comment: This could mean any number of things, and we can only really make wild guesses from here.  Maybe the application is pointing at a different database, maybe it's using different data for authentication, maybe there's some data caching going on, maybe the manual update was for the wrong record, etc.

Comment: If this is an MS Access database with user-level security, then all security information is stored in an *.mdw. You really need to provide a lot more information on your set-up and how you tried to change the password.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a password encryption, In this case you can not just modify the password in the database to login. Check your application.

Comment: Yes there is. How can I modify the password then ?

Answer (score 0):

The various things you say are incompatible with each other. Saving a database with encryption does not require a user name, only a password. If you get the password wrong or do not supply it, the database does not open read-only, it does not open at all. If you are using user level security, the user name and password are not stored "within the database", they are stored in an .mdw file.

Try holding the shift key down while you open the database, you must keep it held until the database if fully open, that is, hold the shift key, open the database, type in the password, continue to hold the shift key.

If you are **not** asked for a password when you hold the shift key, but the file is still read only, check:

- Right-click the file and check the properties
- Check the folder permissions
- If there is a left over .ldb or .laccdb lock file

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear. The login information here refers to the application username and password which are stored in the ms access database (table name : distributor).

Comment: Okay, in that case what happens when you open the database with the shift-key held down?

Comment: I still get the message file has been open in read-only when I open the ms access file while holding the shift-key down.